# Acessar linha e coluna de um array

Tags: php, array

Eu sou iniciante em php. Meu codigo le um arquivo csv e guarda num array. O problema e que eu nao consigo acessar as colunas. Estou usando o php 5.3.3. Alguem sabe como pego a linha e a coluna?

Essa e a minha funcao:

```
    function readCsv($fileName)
 {
     if(!file_exists($fileName) || !is_readable($fileName)) return false;

 $header = null;
 $data = array();
 $lines = file($fileName);

 foreach($lines as $line) {
     $values = str_getcsv($line, ',', '\\');
     if(!$header) $header = $values;
     else $data[] = array_combine($header, $values);
 }

 return $data;
```

}

E essa e a minha saida:

```
    Array
(
    [Section #] => 
    [Q #] => 1
    [Q Type] => MAT
    [Q Title] => 
    [Q Text] => Please rank your 6 preferred sites for your practicum:
    [Bonus?] => 
    [Difficulty] => 
    [Answer] => Boniface (STB)
    [Answer Match] => Rank 2
    [# Responses] => 0
)
Array
(
    [Section #] => 
    [Q #] => 1
    [Q Type] => MAT
    [Q Title] => 
    [Q Text] => Please rank your 6 preferred sites for your practicum:
    [Bonus?] => 
    [Difficulty] => 
    [Answer] => Boniface (STB)
    [Answer Match] => Rank 2
    [# Responses] => 0
)
Array
(
    [Section #] => 
    [Q #] => 1
    [Q Type] => MAT
    [Q Title] => 
    [Q Text] => Please rank your 6 preferred sites for your practicum:
    [Bonus?] => 
    [Difficulty] => 
    [Answer] => Boniface (STB)
    [Answer Match] => Rank 2
    [# Responses] => 0
)
```

Comment: Você quer acessar as linhas e colunas mesmo ou quer pegar os valores?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No php é bem fácil criar e manipular arrays.
Mas é o seguinte:

No seu código você quer acessar uma linha e coluna de um array. Para cada linha do array, você está criando um array com o índice sendo o $header e o valor sendo o $values.

Isso significa que cada linha do array ordinal tem outro array associativo dentro.

Aqui:

`$data[] = array_combine($header, $values);`

Para encontrar a informação dentro desse array, você precisa dar o índice do array $data e ele retornará outro array.

Por exemplo:

`print_r($data[0])` retornará mais ou menos:

```
Array
(
    [Section #] => 
    [Q #] => 1
    [Q Type] => MAT
    [Q Title] => 
    [Q Text] => Please rank your 6 preferred sites for your practicum:
    [Bonus?] => 
    [Difficulty] => 
    [Answer] => Boniface (STB)
    [Answer Match] => Rank 2
    [# Responses] => 0
)
```

Aí você acessa dentro desse array a informação que você quiser. Por exemplo:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($data);$i++){
  $info = $data[$i];

  // agora vamos acessar a Q Text ou qualquer outra coisa

  echo $info["Q Text"] . "<br>";
  echo $info["Answer"];
}
```

Você também pode ler sobre arrays no php.net.

Comment: mas como eu faco para pegar por  exemplo a primeira coluna, elemento 3?

Comment: Valeu, funcionou!